# Command is available in …; The command could not be located

Tags: command-line

I have a problem in my terminal. I've just downloaded an Android emulator and this happens on my terminal. I've been using Ubuntu 12.04.

```
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
 * /bin/lesspipe
 * /usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
Command 'uname' is available in '/bin/uname'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
uname: command not found
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
Command 'sed' is available in '/bin/sed'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sed: command not found
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

Comment: yes... https://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/07/download-and-install-androidsdk-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

i just do what it said..

Comment: Add the output of `/usr/bin/cat ~/.bashrc` as well.

Comment: What does your .bashrc file look like?

Comment: how? i just a new user of ubuntu.. :)

Comment: bash: /usr/bin/cat: No such file or directory

it doesnt work

Comment: Ok, then `/bin/cat` then.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following:

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/sweet/android-sdk-linux/platfrom-tools
```

Now try to execute the commands.

if you want to save it permanently so that you don't need to type it over and over again open `~/.bashrc` using `gedit` by `/usr/bin/gedit ~/.bashrc` and find the line `{PATH}:/home/sweet/android-sdk-linux/platfrom-tools`. Then either delete that line or put a `#` in front of it to comment it out. Then add the following line:

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/sweet/android-sdk-linux/platfrom-tools
```

now save the file and from the terminal run `source ~/.bashrc` so that your path is properly set from the current terminal session.

Comment: it doesnt work..

Comment: whats the error message showing now?

Comment: there's no message..

Comment: i did it but when i trying to open gedit


Command 'gedit' is available in '/usr/bin/gedit'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
gedit: command not found

Comment: @SweetzelynSarmiento: Did you run `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` beforehand?

Comment: Also whats the output of `/bin/echo $PATH`?

Comment: {PATH}:/home/sweet/android-sdk-linux/platfrom-tools

Comment: Ok, run `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/sweet/android-sdk-linux/platfrom-tools` and then try again from the same terminal.

Comment: yeah it works.. but do i need to do that always when i want to run terminal?

Comment: @SweetzelynSarmiento: check my edits in the answer.

Comment: ok.. hhmmm.. i have now 1 problem in my terminal.. when i minimize it. it lost..

Comment: if i do that i can now use android emulator properly?

Comment: `/home/sweet/android-sdk-linux/platfrom-tools` is added to the path so if you put it correctly then android emulator will work well.

Comment: @Fabby: Should i say 'you are a genius' once again? Will say that whenever i will get a chance to chat ;)

Comment: From now on, I'm not going to leave any comments any more when I upvote you!  ;-)  :P

Comment: @Fabby: lol..thats a good one too, genius!! :p

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>
Login your account with username and password.

```
sudo mv /etc/environment /etc/environment.bak
sudo touch /etc/environment
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Underrated answer